# Invalid or Unexpected token while creating angular project

Tags: angular

c:\AngularPro>ng new Employee
? Would you like to add Angular routing? No
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS
Invalid or unexpected token

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm i -g @angular/cli@latest`. After that try to run your command. and in case of css you need to press enter on css option instead of typing it.